# Copying data into array without use of array_agg() in POSTGRESQL

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, flask

I have read only access to a database in which I would like to aggregate string literals that belong to the same key. The Postgres database is not up to date and array_agg() is not supported, but I need them to be in an array for other purposes. I am currently copying data from that database into a csv file, and then need to copy from the csv file to my new database with array column type.

For example, what I have is:

```
author ... "BOOK1";"BOOK2";"BOOK3"
```

which results in

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "BOOK1"
DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

When I try to copy it from the csv to my database.
How can I can I get this in an array format without array_agg()?

Comment: You may want to post the expected output

Comment: Try this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=0b299077ebb1e0fbbb5799403db8abaa

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate the values with `{` and }` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html

```
a="BOOK1,BOOK2,BOOK3"
print('{'+a+'}')
```

Comment: do I just need to write a script to manually add brackets to this column? there are about 40k rows so I don't know how efficient that would be

Comment: I do not have much experience with particular data type but documentation tells you to do so. Maybe use pandas do so.